# Multiplication properties about trace of two operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, trace

Consider two operators $A$ and $B$, their functions $e^A$ and $e^B$ and a basis that mutual diagonalizes $A$ and $B$. Can I say that

$$Tr\left[e^Ae^B\right]=Tr\left[e^A\right]Tr\left[e^B\right]~?$$

If so, why?

Comment: take two 2x2 diagonal matrices to construct a simple counterexample

Comment: probably best suited to [math.se]

Comment: @Phoenix87, that probably could be fleshed out into an answer.

Comment: I agree, Kyle kanos. Thank you, @Phoenix87.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we want to craft a counterexample. Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ diagonal matrix $\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$. Then its exponential is $e^A = \text{diag}(e^{\lambda_1},e^{\lambda_2})$, whereas its trace is $e^{\lambda_1}+e^{\lambda_2}$. If $B$ is another diagonal matrix then it commutes with $A$ and therefore $e^Ae^B = e^{A+B}$. If $B=\text{diag}(\mu_1,\mu_2)$, then
$$e^{A+B}=\text{diag}(e^{\lambda_1+\mu_1},e^{\lambda_2+\mu_2}),$$
whose trace is $e^{\lambda_1+\mu_1} + e^{\lambda_2+\mu_2}$, which clearly differs from the product of the traces of $e^A$ and $e^B$ because of extra terms.